# XML value to XML node conversion using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to write XSLT file for following input XML to output XML, is it possible XSLT to convert the value of input xml as node in output XML? how can I implement this?

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rows>
 <Row><xml_data_name/> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>persons</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>person</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>username</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value>JS1</xml_data_value> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value>John</xml_data_value> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>family-name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>family-name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value>Smith</xml_data_value> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>family-name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>person</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>person</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>username</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value>MI1</xml_data_value> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value>Morka</xml_data_value> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>family-name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>family-name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value>Ismincius</xml_data_value> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>family-name</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>person</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name>persons</xml_data_name> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
 <Row><xml_data_name/> <xml_data_value/> </Row>
</Rows>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<persons>
  <person username="JS1">
    <name>John</name>
    <family-name>Smith</family-name>
  </person>
  <person username="MI1">
    <name>Morka</name>
    <family-name>Ismincius</family-name>
  </person>
</persons>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use xsl:element like

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <!-- Note {} brackets in name attribute -->
    <xsl:element name="{xml_data_name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="xml_data_value" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

What would be greater problem is a structure of output because it is not easy to decide which rows should be nested, which rows should transform into an attribute rather than element etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's one of the weirdest data formats I've ever seen! Are you sure you can't get whatever produced this to produce something more reasonable?

I think the solution has to be recursion: you want a function that takes a sequence of rows as input; it outputs an element whose name is the name of the first element in the sequence with no data value and whose content is obtained by a recursive call that passes all rows after that first row up to the next row with no data value and the same name, then calls itself to process all rows after that row. Not easy, and certainly takes more time than I allow myself for answering SO questions!